# Admin Module showing empty Page?

Tags: magento-1.6, php-5.4

I have created Admin Controller,When I hit on menu it's showing empty page.

Why it's not showing? Can any one tell me?

my code is:

**College->Svccs->etc->config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <College_Svccs>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </College_Svccs>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <svccs>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>College_Svccs</module>
                    <frontName>svccs</frontName>
                </args>
            </svccs>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <svccs>
                    <file>svccs.xml</file>
                </svccs>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <svccs>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>College_Svccs</module>
                    <frontName>svccs</frontName>
                </args>
            </svccs>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <svccs module="svccs">
                <title>Svccs Branches</title>
                <sort_order>88</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <svcet module="svccs">
                        <title>Svcet</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>svccs/adminhtml_index</action>
                    </svcet>
                </children>
            </svccs>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <College_Svccs>
                            <title>Svccs Branches Module</title>
                            <sort_order>88</sort_order>
                        </College_Svccs>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <svccs>
                    <file>svccs.xml</file>
                </svccs>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <svccs>
                <class>College_Svccs_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>svccs_resource</resourceModel>
            </svccs>
            <svccs_resource>
                <class>College_Svccs_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <svccs>
                        <table>svccs</table>
                    </svccs>
                </entities>
            </svccs_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <svccs_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>College_Svccs</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </svccs_setup>
            <svccs_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </svccs_read>
            <svccs_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </svccs_write>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <svccs>
                <class>College_Svccs_Block</class>
            </svccs>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <svccs>
                <class>College_Svccs_Helper</class>
            </svccs>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

**College->Svccs->Block->Adminhtml->Grid.php**

```
<?php

class College_Svccs_Block_Adminhtml_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        //where is the controller
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_svccs';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'svccs';
        //text in the admin header
        $this->_headerText = 'Svccs Department';
        //value of the add button
        $this->_addButtonLabel = 'Add Svccs College';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**College->Svccs->Block->Adminhtml->Svccs->Gird.php**

```
<?php

class College_Svccs_Block_Adminhtml_Svccs_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('svccsGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('college_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

        $collection = Mage::getModel('svccs/svccs')->getCollection();
        Mage::log((array)$collection);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('college_id',
            array(
                'header' => 'Test ID',
                'align'  =>'right',
                'width'  => '50px',
                'index'  => 'college_id',
            ));
        $this->addColumn('collegename',
            array(
                'header' => 'College Name',
                'align'  =>'left',
                'index'  => 'collegename',
            ));
       $this->addColumn('telephone', array(
            'header' => 'Telephone',
            'align'  =>'left',
            'index'  => 'telephone',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }

}
```

**College->Svccs->controllers->Adminhtml->IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class College_Svccs_Adminhtml_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**adminhtml->default->College->Svccs->layout->svccs.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <svccs_adminhtml_index_index>
            <reference name="content">
                <block name="svccs_svccs" type="svccs/adminhtml_grid" ></block>
            </reference>
        </svccs_adminhtml_index_index>
    </layout>
```

Comment: have you put some debug into the indexAction to make sure that you are getting this far?

Comment: @DavidManners, I configure the debug in indexAction it's working, but when I configure the debut in Grid.php file it's not working? I think Layout file is not calling! Can you suggest me.

Comment: check that `$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()` includes the layout handle that you have in your xml

Comment: @DavidManners, where I write this?

Comment: in the controller action after loadlayout. make sure you log it or var_dump so you can see the output

Comment: @DavidManners, I got `2013-10-28T12:46:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [0] => default
    [1] => STORE_admin
    [2] => THEME_adminhtml_default_default
    [3] => svccs_adminhtml_index_index
)` this. I think my theme is not applying? Can you suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You've called your controller '$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_svccs';' but the filename seems to be controller/Adminhtml/IndexController.php while it should be controller/Adminhtml/SvccsController.php.

Comment: I change the `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_svccs'` to `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_index'`, still it's showing empty page.

Comment: Hi Peter,  I configure the debug in indexAction it's working, but when I configure the debut in Grid.php file it's not working? I think Layout file is not calling! Can you suggest me?